# lmfit - unable to form simple minimisation problem

Tags: python, minimization, lmfit

I am struggling to get what ought to be a fairly basic minimisation problem setup correctly using the lmfit package. Here is my code, which serves as a dumbed-down version of what I am working on.

```
import lmfit

class test_class:

    def __init__(self,A=None):

        self.A = A

def my_obj_fn(B,C=1.0,the_class=None):

    D = abs(B + C + the_class.A)

    return D

if __name__ == '__main__':

    awesome_class_instance = test_class(A=2.0)
    C_val = 3.0

    my_params = lmfit.Parameters()
    my_params.add('B',7.0,min=-10.0,max=12.0)

    key_word_args = {'C': C_val,
                    'the_class': awesome_class_instance,
                    }

    result = lmfit.minimize(

            fcn = my_obj_fn,
            params = my_params,
            kws = key_word_args,
            method = 'differential_evolution'
    )

    print(result)
```

The error I am getting is as follows

```
    ValueError: '3.0' is not a Parameters object

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    ....
    RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'
```

Clearly I am not setting up the code correctly. The documentation has not been helpful in understanding why this is not correct. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: According to the docs, the `fcn` needs to have the signature `fcn(params,*args,**kws)` where `params` is an instance of `Parameters`. See: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#lmfit.minimizer.minimize

Comment: The examples here might be useful: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#writing-a-fitting-function. For example, notice how their `residual` function uses parameters called `period`, `shift` and `decay`, but it doesn't have those params directly in its signature. It has its first argument as `pars`, and it accesses `pars.valuesdict()` by key to get at the individual parameters.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I thought that my function was already in that form? I only have a single free parameter, 'B'. Edit: Oh I think I see what you mean, let me attempt something new

Comment: You'd need to do something like that `residual` function in the above link does. So the first argument of `my_obj_fun` (let's call the argument `my_pars`) would be an instance of `Parameters`. Then you'd extract your parameter from that: `B=my_pars.valuesdict()['B']`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I've got things working now : )